# Why doesn't manual transaction rollback work in Django?

Tags: python, django, translation

My environment is python2.7.3 and django1.4.1

I am using MySQL with MyISAM tables.

my test code:

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from myproject import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from myproject.models import *
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_manually
def test_trans():
    r=tab1.objects.get(no="1")
    r.value=100
    r.save()
    transaction.rollback()#I already rollback here, but data is still being updated to the database

def main():
    try:
        test_trans()
    except:
        pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It seems that transaction.rollback() is not rolling back my transaction, as data is still being updated to the database.

Comment: Please tell us which database you're using.  MySQL?  And if it's MySQL, which table engine are you using (e.g. MyISAM / InnoDB)

Comment: MyISAM or InnoDB?  Or other?

Comment: that is MyISAM,Perhaps I know why, thank you very much

Comment: I've updated my answer so that others can be helped by this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL with MyISAM, it doesn't support transactions.  Change your tables to InnoDB if you want to use this functionality.

I add the following to my settings.py to do this automatically (when calling syncdb):

```
DATABASE_OPTIONS = {"init_command": "SET storage_engine=INNODB"}
```